# How to setDataSource loop playing music in Android?

Tags: java, android

```
       String path ="";

        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(path); //path url mp3
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        textTotalDuration.setText(milliSecondsToTimer(mediaPlayer.getDuration()));
```

Example read all mp3 in the folder download or specific path

Comment: Could you provide more information about what you want to achieve and improve your question?

Answer (score 0):

It will be better if you explain you question more. As far as I understand your questing, you want to loop your media player.
if you want to loop your media player then add

```
mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are asking about how to add data source path. So, if you are asking that, than try this:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Download/music.mp3";
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(path); 
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        textTotalDuration.setText(milliSecondsToTimer(mediaPlayer.getDuration()));
```

And if you are asking about loop media play then:

```
mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

**read all mp3 & m4a & wav & aac in the folder Music :**

```
private int trackIndex = 0;
private List<String> tracks;
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

private void initMediaPlayer() {
    tracks = new ArrayList<>();
    addTracksInDirectory("/storage/emulated/0/Music/");////path url mp3
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    setTrack(trackIndex);
}

private void setTrack(int index) {
    try {
        trackIndex = index;
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(tracks.get(trackIndex));
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.start();

        // Listen for the end of the track and play the next one
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(mediaPlayer -> {
            trackIndex = (trackIndex + 1) % tracks.size();
            setTrack(trackIndex);
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Handle the error
    }
}

private void addTracksInDirectory(String directoryPath) {
    File directory = new File(directoryPath);
    File[] files = directory.listFiles();
    if (files != null) {
        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isFile() && isAudioFile(file.getName())) {
                tracks.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
    }
}

private boolean isAudioFile(String fileName) {
    String[] audioFileExtensions = {".mp3", ".m4a", ".wav", ".aac"};
    for (String extension : audioFileExtensions) {
        if (fileName.endsWith(extension)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all create a list and add all the songs.

```
final ArrayList<String> playList = new ArrayList<String>();
// Add yours songs to the list that needs to be played NEXT.
```

Now add a completion listener for the playlist, so after current song is completed it will play the next.

```
player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {

                if(playList.size() == 0) return; // played all so return.

                String path = playList.remove(0); // get & remove the song from the playlist we are gonna play.

                // Play the song
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                mediaPlayer.start();
    
            }
        });
```